# pip and pip3 Traceback error

Tags: python, linux

I am running Linux Mint 18.2 and have python 2.7.12 and 3.5.2 installed.
pip and pip3 used to work but recently I just get an error `pip3 --version`
gives the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==9.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip3')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 542, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2569, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2229, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2235, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/home/norman/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/home/norman/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/home/norman/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 47, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.cachecontrol import CacheControlAdapter
ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.cachecontrol'
```

I have tried various suggestions but none have worked. I get the same with pip
Any ideas please

Comment: "I have tried various suggestions" - could you highlight what you have tried?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `pip3` command ... my approach has been `python3 -m pip install/do whatever`

Comment: upgrade OpenSSL

Comment: Here's the [thread on github](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2345).  Can you run `python3 -c "import ssl"` without error?  If not, you need to fix your python installation.  Did you use a package manager of some kind, or did you build it yourself?

Comment: I have  openssl 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.10  and pyopenssl installed via the package manager. Also was asked to install python3-cachecontrol, python3-lockfile, python3-packaging,
python3-progress and python3-retrying. As they were already installed I reinstalled them all.

Comment: @Patrick Haugh It works without errors so I guess it isn't a problem with python itself